# LAMBDA in c syntax

Tags: c, lambda, macros

I found a tutorial about emulating lambda in c, but I can not fully get the declaring way. 
why callback mentioned twice, and what is the use of curly brackets "scope" and outer parentheses.

tutorial link :
https://blog.noctua-software.com/c-lambda.html

This code working on gcc 4.9.2 compiler by the way.

```
#define LAMBDA(c_) ({ c_ _;})
void func(int nb, void (*f)(int)) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < nb; i++) f(i);
}


int main()
{
func(4, ({  //parentheses ??
    void callback(int v) { printf("%d\n", v); }
    callback;   // callback here what it does mean?
}));
}
```

The last step of declaring.

```
#define LAMBDA(c_) ({ c_ _;})
int main()
{
  func(4, LAMBDA(void _(int v) {
    printf("%d\n", v);
   }));
 }
```

Comment: Where `LAMBDA` is used at all in this code? Have you forgot to post some part of it? *Update:* So you mixed together different snippets from the tutorial.

Comment: I mentioned tutorial link, I want to understand the syntax mentioned above.  It works on gcc 4.9.2

Comment: As the tutorial says, it is non-standard to have nested functions.

Comment: Yes, but anyone can explain the syntax way.

Comment: Read the wikipage about [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a GCC extension, ['compound statements in expressions'](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

TL;DR: When `({...})` is encountered in an expression, all statements inside are executed, and the value of the last statement is treated as the value of the `({...})` itself.

E.g.:

```
int x = ({int a = 1, b = 2; a + b;}); // x = 3
```

---

Normally you're not allowed to defined functions inside other functions, but that compiles because of [another GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

Comment: Thank you , that is what I wanted to know exactly !

Answer (score 1):

`({ ... })` is extension in GCC, statement in expression. It means you can embed any statement into expression. It's really cool extension.

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement%20Exprs) you can read more about it.

Comment: what about callback under function declaration ?

Comment: It's another extension [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).